# When refering to plural nouns, when to use c'est and when to use ce sont?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pluriel

I was reading an article and came across these usages:

1. En réalité ces symboles, CE SONT les symboles...
2. Les premiers attentats, C'ÉTAIT contre le journal...

Why is "symboles" treated as a plural noun in "ce sont" while "attentats" is treated as a singular one in "c'était"?

I have come across similar usages several times in different materials now, so I don't think this is an issue exclusive to this particular article I am citing here.

Comment: Beware that your second case is not representative of a singular used instead of a plural. Only the singular is possible in ***C'était** contre le journal* because *ce* + *être* is not followed by a plural. The pronoun *ce* stays singular: ***cela** était contre le journal*.

Comment: *Les premiers attentats, **ils** étaient contre le journal* would be ok but here, the meaning is *That was against the newspaper*.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you so much, I certainly learned a new thing from your comment.